# CentOS7 Networking issue

Tags: networking, centos7

I have a CentOS7 - running the latest CentOS7 software - server with two NICs, one of which is giving me grief.

Initially it had only one active interface (`p3p1` - fibre interface) and everything was working fine.  When we added the configuration for card #2 (`em1` - copper) which is a local, non-routed connection, we lost the ability to ping by hostname (eg. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)).  If I use the actual IP address (eg. 8.8.8.8), ping works fine.

The routing table is good, and I tried stopping `firewalld` to see if that was the culprit - it made no difference.

Comment: What happens when you run `nslookup` on `www.google.com`?

Comment: Does your /etc/resolv.conf file look sane ?

Comment: nslookup gives a connection timeout.  For completeness, I ran nslookup in interactive mode, set the DNS to use 8.8.8.8 (the Google DNS IP) and did a lookup for www.google.com - same thing.

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf looks fine - three nameserver lines, and no search domain